# How can I change arrow size scale depends on edge's scale in networkx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I'm trying to draw some maps, and the default setting of edge is not that beautiful.
I mean, if the edge's width is wider than certain point, well, the arrowhead looks like... you know.
Maybe you want to check it with the pic.

[image]

Well, now you see what the big edge looks like.
Anyway, you might noticed that I already set the node's scale to be different. It differs by the in and out degree values.

I used this code for it

```
spec_year_sum['width'] = spec_year_sum['value_diff'].abs()*25 +0.05 #just adjusting thing
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(spec_year_sum, 'reporteriso3', 'partneriso3', ['width','color'], create_using= nx.DiGraph())
widths = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'width')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,width=list(widths.values()))
```

I thought the arrowsize would work in a same way. So I tried this

```
spec_year_sum['arrow'] = spec_year_sum['value_diff'].abs()*25 +0.05 #just adjusting thing
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(spec_year_sum, 'reporteriso3', 'partneriso3', ['width','color','arrow'], create_using= nx.DiGraph())
arrow = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'width')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,arrowsize=list(arrow.values()), width=list(widths.values()))
```

But it only gives me this Error

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

If I set 'arrowsize = 5' or some fixed constant number, it work fine but It doesn't change its scale, obviously.
So, is there a way I can make arrowsize to be changed by some value or edge's scale?
Any walk-around is welcomed as well.

Thank you for reading this.

P.S, FYI when you `print(widths)`:

```
{('JPN', 'CHN'): 11.114124560740605, ('JPN', 'USA'): 6.067685015477913, ('JPN', 'KOR'): 0.8594140135634463, ('JPN', 'HKG'): 1.1093725559917624, ('JPN', 'MEX'): 0.276025839860663, ('JPN', 'DEU'): 0.44619440997892923, ('JPN', 'ITA'): 0.19515792822148842, ('JPN', 'GBR'): 1.1960942151446825, ('CHN', 'USA'): 0.14267137997503523, ('CHN', 'HKG'): 1.3878267347325648, ('CHN', 'DEU'): 0.42993733613616825, ('CHN', 'JPN'): 0.4565106349404802, ('CHN', 'KOR'): 0.17792469978445263, ('CHN', 'GBR'): 0.07703547752128974, ('CHN', 'ITA'): 0.2703872675489626, ('CHN', 'MEX'): 0.27981096626924296, ('EU', 'USA'): 1.3720780481708696, ('EU', 'CHN'): 5.7435004142786275, ('EU', 'MEX'): 4.24113661788301, ('EU', 'KOR'): 4.304475660096702, ('EU', 'JPN'): 0.4156210427676585, ('EU', 'HKG'): 0.2549234613477606, ('USA', 'MEX'): 0.912333153838307, ('USA', 'CHN'): 3.9482111575615852, ('USA', 'DEU'): 0.9490808520814704, ('USA', 'JPN'): 0.05853348169066854, ('USA', 'GBR'): 0.23908714893234662, ('USA', 'KOR'): 0.4430417007329833, ('USA', 'HKG'): 0.09706343387291005, ('USA', 'ITA'): 0.2788793702576744, ('KOR', 'CHN'): 6.404745805730112, ('KOR', 'USA'): 1.4997797280635512, ('KOR', 'MEX'): 0.3297179776860301, ('KOR', 'HKG'): 0.5321655794910432, ('KOR', 'JPN'): 0.3674243383553449, ('KOR', 'DEU'): 0.05022979376125244, ('KOR', 'GBR'): 0.12293796585725561, ('KOR', 'ITA'): 0.06497341896656673, ('HKG', 'CHN'): 8.465283935860377, ('HKG', 'USA'): 0.11306253633479167, ('HKG', 'JPN'): 0.12307885309601546, ('HKG', 'DEU'): 0.05717979479364361, ('HKG', 'KOR'): 0.05388446467854105, ('HKG', 'GBR'): 0.060420948299576636, ('HKG', 'MEX'): 0.05250287685473163, ('HKG', 'ITA'): 0.05912901943334446, ('DEU', 'CHN'): 8.47359387796156, ('DEU', 'USA'): 8.412414463631267, ('DEU', 'GBR'): 1.701503427941779, ('DEU', 'ITA'): 0.34677584151273066, ('DEU', 'MEX'): 0.9879088836937722, ('DEU', 'KOR'): 0.9890697961146189, ('DEU', 'JPN'): 0.11712260539107032, ('DEU', 'HKG'): 0.11115009531802277, ('MEX', 'USA'): 1.8773849806353298, ('MEX', 'DEU'): 0.0663837939024082, ('MEX', 'CHN'): 0.07238228803330322, ('MEX', 'HKG'): 0.06025566917713725, ('MEX', 'JPN'): 0.05265674704128035, ('MEX', 'GBR'): 0.052374485049362554, ('MEX', 'ITA'): 0.05040824677750046, ('MEX', 'KOR'): 0.055774286872335294, ('GBR', 'USA'): 0.538294940775951, ('GBR', 'DEU'): 0.5002385473995273, ('GBR', 'CHN'): 0.11040044745763103, ('GBR', 'KOR'): 0.24598405316003608, ('GBR', 'ITA'): 0.08272435730373967, ('GBR', 'JPN'): 0.0976471480865812, ('GBR', 'MEX'): 0.07098944369172572, ('GBR', 'HKG'): 0.09763797419384453, ('ITA', 'USA'): 0.6929598076613824, ('ITA', 'DEU'): 0.21393507916288923, ('ITA', 'CHN'): 1.4294763998458857, ('ITA', 'GBR'): 0.44879756221456885, ('ITA', 'MEX'): 0.10266623609598621, ('ITA', 'KOR'): 0.404970044792893, ('ITA', 'JPN'): 0.11280067443113567, ('ITA', 'HKG'): 0.05940778196496439}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain non-rounded arrows on fat lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67251763/how-to-obtain-non-rounded-arrows-on-fat-lines)

Comment: Looks like arrowsize only accepts an int. You can loop through each edge and call draw_networkx_edges for each one and provide the specific arrowsize value for that edge

Comment: @Frodnar Hi! Thanks for the link. Actually that's what I wanted, but the simple/fancy arrowstyle has minimum width which is quite thick for what I intend to make. Thanks again!

Comment: @cookesd Hi! Thanks for the comment. But actually, I tried that as well so I tested with ```int(round(widths,0))``` kinda thing. But it gives me the same error so I'm not sure what would causing the problem as well...